# Is *.runsettings file compatible with 2010 Visual Studio? is there any mandatory conditions like VS2012 is required?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage, vs-unit-testing-framework

What is the minimum version of Visual studio is supported for runsettings file?
VS2010 or VS2012?

Answer (score 0):

`.testsettings` file is no longer included in a unit test project. The newer test framework, introduced in Visual Studio 2012, can be configured using a `.runsettings` file.

> If you use a `.testsettings` file, the MSTest test framework will be
>   used to run your tests.

This runs more slowly and does not allow you to run tests from third-party test frameworks.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx)

Comment: Our project is in VS2010. Previously we had .testsettings file for Unit test case running. Now we need to measure code coverage also.

Comment: Our project is in VS2010. Previously we had .testsettings file for Unit test case running. Now we need to measure code coverage also. Please help me in understanding better with below qns. 1)Can I continue with existing .testsettings file now to achieve the same? 2)If I want to create .runsettings file newly,  my project has to migrate for VS2012 or can i proceed VS2010 also? 3)If we can't migrate our project to VS2012 now, how can I proceed further?